# Kernel update without reboot

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reloading a kernel “live” in CentOS / RHEL 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/351270/reloading-a-kernel-live-in-centos-rhel-6)

How can i update kernel on Centos **without reboot .?**

I found ksplice but it is not supported for Centos.

Regards,

Comment: KSplice is really the only option.  If KSplice doesn't support CentOS or RHEL, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: CentOS lets you upgrade any time. But you have to reboot to activate the new kernel. What part of the boot-process is actually causing you headaches?

Comment: if you need solid uptime, think about using openbsd . You get a lot less kernel updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man kexec`:

> kexec is a system call that enables you to load and boot into another
>   kernel from the currently running kernel.  kexec performs  the
>   function  of  the boot loader from within the kernel. The primary
>   difference between a standard system boot and a kexec boot is that the
>   hardware initialization normally performed by the BIOS or firmware
>   (depending on architecture) is not performed during a kexec boot. This
>   has the effect of reducing the time required for a reboot.

To install it: `yum install kexec-tools`

Comment: It minimize the reboot process. But still there is a down time and not as efficient as KSplice.

Comment: Look at 3dinfluece below. If this is a production server KSplice is not enough to keep the system up to date. BIOS-updates often also require a reboot (as do some other firmware-updates). So there would be better a second server able to take over the sessions.

Answer (score 2):

With KSplice not supporting your OS you're out of luck.

Comment: @larsks Centos is not supported by Ksplice at the current time
http://www.ksplice.com/pricing

Comment: @Nils I want to update the kernel without down time, If i'm using a production server it will be a problem to reboot the server every time i update the kernel.

Comment: The CentOS-Kernel is binary compatible to the RH or unbreakable Linux Kernel. So what?

Comment: @RamyAllam if uptime is that important then you need to come up with a HA strategy that involves more than one machine with failover.  That way you can always take one off line for maintenance.

Comment: How does KSplice replace active running kernel modules?

Comment: @Nils In order to use the RH release, It required access key from ksplice.com and redhat.com. So that i can not use the RH rpms on Centos

Comment: You can install it on CentOS, it just won't run `The Ksplice Uptrack for RHEL trial provides access to rebootless updates for RHEL 5 and 6 systems only.  If you have any questions, please contact ksplice-support_ww@oracle...`

Comment: @RamyAllam so you open a direct channel via internet for kernel-updates? I hope these updates are signed (as are RPMs).

Comment: From Ksplice FAQ: http://www.ksplice.com/uptrack/faq . Does Ksplice Uptrack use cryptography?
  Yes.  All network traffic is encrypted, and all updates are
  cryptographically signed.